# Is there possibility to upload image and text using Pinterest Domain API?

Tags: pinterest

I have to upload images and text from Android app only using Pinterest Domain API. I had spent more time on this.

Comment: Please post some code showing what you have tried already, and any error messages you have received

Comment: HI ste-fu. I want API Details for uploading the image and text using only via Pinterest Domain Web API.i had seen only get info using  Pinterest Domain Web API. For Posting i dint seen any URL. if there is any url plz guide me.